# Remove filter description in enhanced grid dojo

Tags: dojo, dojo.gridx

I would like to remove the filter description in dojo enhanced grid.

Here is the image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The message is part of FilterBar of the plugin Filter. Try getting the filter bar from Filter like

```
var filterBar = dijit.byId('grid').pluginMgr.getPlugin('filter').filterBar;
```

Next, the text is set with attach point name as 'statusBarNode'

Once you the attachpoint, you can change the text by using set() method or innerHTML

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response, can you share an jsfiddle example for this, which will help me..